# Intervals timer from timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I've found following simple script for timer from specific timestamp:

```
var el = '.timer';
var start = 1553000000,
    cDisplay = $(el);
var format = function (t) {
    var hours = Math.floor(t / 3600),
        minutes = Math.floor(t / 60 % 60),
        seconds = Math.floor(t % 60),
        arr = [];
    if (hours > 0) {
        arr.push(hours == 1 ? '1 hr' : hours + 'hrs');
    }
    if (minutes > 0 || hours > 0) {
        arr.push(minutes > 1 ? minutes + ' mins' : minutes + ' min');
    }
    if (seconds > 0 || minutes > 0 || hours > 0) {
        arr.push(seconds > 1 ? seconds + ' secs' : seconds + ' sec');
    }
    cDisplay.html(arr.join(' '));
};
setInterval(function () {
    format(new Date().getTime() / 1000 - start);
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4eqat9yc/

I want to create a script which would imitate traffic lights cycles, for example there's 40 seconds of red light, then 30 seconds of green light and it repeats indefinitely.

Output should be red text counting down 40 seconds, then green text counting down 30 seconds, taking starting time of the cycles from timestamp. (so for example I could start script in the middle of the cycle and it will show correct time left of this interval)

Could you guys help me with this one?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out logic with simple python equation how to determine which interval runs currently:
lets simplify it into intervals of 5 and 8 seconds, first is 5 second 
But I am stuck how to start it with JS

```
x = 5
y = 8
t = 96

z = t-(t/(x+y)*(x+y)) //python divides without remainder

if z >= x and z > y:
    print y
elif  z >= x and z < y:
    print y
elif  z < x and z < y:
    print x
```